DevOps git retains checked in data when switching branch in VS 2022
What's happening is I'm working on a branch and check in the changes, then switch to the master. Git tab shows all the files that I had just checked in on the other branch...
If I pull the master it cleans it up, or I can delete the changes to manually remove them.
But I need it to remove those checked in changes so I change to the master as it should be.


I'm working on a branch and check in the changes, then switch to the master. Git tab shows all the files that I had just checked in on the other branch...

Based on my test, when I add the changes to other branch without commit the changes, I can reproduce the similar issue in Visual Studio.

The cause of the issue is that the created/changed files are not put in any branches until you add and commit them. So no matter which branch you are on, the file will still be there locally.
To solve this issue, you can switch back to other branch and commit the changes, then it won't appear on the master branch any more.
For example:

Result:


Yeah I have already committed the code then it comes back when I switch branches.... after that if I pull the branch I move to all those changes dissappear, it's as if it's not refreshing the local data when I switch branch

@CoolDaemonX can you share some screenshots about the steps of the issue? This will be helpful to solve the issue

It doesn't appear to be doing it now... if it ends up doing it again I'll grab the screenshots

@CoolDaemonX As far as I know, if we commit the changes to target branch, it will not show the files when you switch the branches. The situation you encountered before may also be caused by VS cache. It can be solved when you restart VS.

It looks to have been a cache issue. I'm no longer seeing the issue bar the odd bin or vs folder being created that it's not saying as ignored yet

@CoolDaemonX can you share the screenshot about the new issue？I will try to give some help.

@CoolDaemonX If you need to ignore the vs folder when doing git changes, you can add the .gitignore file to your repo to ignore the vs folder. Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/ignore-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2022#edit-a-gitignore-file

Yes,  I've solved this problem with file changes,  however I notice if I ignore the files in .vs bin or obj folders and commit the ignore the master branch does not see the ignores until the branch has been pushed to master... it's not much of a problem.

@CoolDaemonX You need to add the ignorefile to the branch once and then pull the branch to do the changes. Then you will see the .vs and bin folder will be ignored.
